# how to retrive maximun version related to post?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have two tables:

```
table posts
id
text

table old_posts
id 
post_id
text
version
```

the relation is one to many between `post` and `old_posts` when the user edits his/her post I save the old version in `old_posts` but I need to increment the version number so I have first to get the maximum version for that post.

how I achieve this?

Comment: as every time you save a new instance of the post within old_posts, you just need to count the number of old_posts by post_id

Comment: @Thamer that should work, do you mind tell me how to count  then is it Old_post::where('post_id', $post_id)->get()->count ?

Comment: check my answer, what you have written here in comments will use the Collection to calculate the number of version instead of SQL query with eloquent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this situation, you don't need to use the version column within the database table, instead of that you just need to count the number of the old_post's rows table.

the query should be like below with eloquent:

```
$versions = Old_post::where('post_id', $post_id)->count();
```